# Find second least represented region across all teams

Tags: postgresql

I need to find second least represented region across all teams. Region can be duplicated from country to country.

So the goal is to count engineers regions in teams and get second least value of the count.

I've tried so far to make something like this

```
select 
    countries.region, 
    teams.name, 
    count(contries.region) 
from teams 
join engineers on teams.id = engineers.team_id 
join countries on countries.id = engineers.country_id
where countries.region in (
    select 
        countries.region
    from (select 
            countries.region,
            rownumber() over () as rownum 
            from countries
         ) as x 
    where
        x.rownum = 2
);
```

The references between tables is not good so I don't have any idea of how I can make it

```
sqlhunt_development=# \d engineers
                                     Table "public.engineers"
   Column   |            Type             |                       Modifiers
------------+-----------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------
 id         | bigint                      | not null default nextval('engineers_id_seq'::regclass)
 first_name | character varying           |
 last_name  | character varying           |
 age        | integer                     |
 email      | character varying           |
 country_id | bigint                      |
 team_id    | bigint                      |
 created_at | timestamp without time zone | not null
 updated_at | timestamp without time zone | not null
Indexes:
    "engineers_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "index_engineers_on_country_id" btree (country_id)
    "index_engineers_on_team_id" btree (team_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "fk_rails_48c685314b" FOREIGN KEY (country_id) REFERENCES countries(id)
    "fk_rails_5c44cd68ac" FOREIGN KEY (team_id) REFERENCES teams(id)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "bookshelves" CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_13dec3ee94" FOREIGN KEY (engineer_id) REFERENCES engineers(id)
    TABLE "engineer_programming_languages" CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_3a4377ed71" FOREIGN KEY (engineer_id) REFERENCES engineers(id)

sqlhunt_development=# \d teams
                                        Table "public.teams"
      Column      |            Type             |                     Modifiers
------------------+-----------------------------+----------------------------------------------------
 id               | bigint                      | not null default nextval('teams_id_seq'::regclass)
 name             | character varying           |
 floor            | integer                     |
 features_shipped | integer                     |
 current_bugs     | integer                     |
 created_at       | timestamp without time zone | not null
 updated_at       | timestamp without time zone | not null
Indexes:
    "teams_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "engineers" CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_5c44cd68ac" FOREIGN KEY (team_id) REFERENCES teams(id)

sqlhunt_development=# \d countries
                                     Table "public.countries"
   Column   |            Type             |                       Modifiers
------------+-----------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------
 id         | bigint                      | not null default nextval('countries_id_seq'::regclass)
 name       | character varying           |
 capital    | character varying           |
 region     | character varying           |
 population | integer                     |
 area       | integer                     |
 created_at | timestamp without time zone | not null
 updated_at | timestamp without time zone | not null
Indexes:
    "countries_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "engineers" CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_48c685314b" FOREIGN KEY (country_id) REFERENCES countries(id)
```

Output at all should be:

```
count |    region    
-------+------------+
   146 | Africa   
   159 | Oceania         
   159 | Europe         
   160 | NA       
   170 | SA       
   171 | SEA     
(8 rows)
```

Goal is to get this:

```
count |    region    
-------+------------+  
   159 | Oceania          
(8 rows)
```

Comment: I tried formatting the SQL you posted to make it a bit easier to follow. That said, what you posted is not valid. Please fix it so it is possible to run without having to guess at the true intention.

Comment: @Z4-tier I Understand that it's not valid, I was asking for help because I can't understand how to fix this)

Comment: ok, well, i think you can make the join conditions valid by writing it like this: `teams join engineers on teams.id = engineers.team_id join countries on countries.id = engineers.country_id `

Comment: @Z4-tier I did as you suggested but can't see why `count` saying that he is missing from clause entry for table `countries`

Comment: Please edit your question and add sample data with expected output. It will help us to understand your problem better

Comment: @ArunPalanisamy I edited question. Sample data isn't something that I can post in here. Because there so many references between each other and i confused a bit xD

Comment: @Lotarc, I can understand. But without that,it is tough for us to give exact answers . Without understanding the relationship of each table, the answers may not suit your problem. If you can make a [fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=06073f8adae8d59fb89c8a415d4b398f) , it would help.

Comment: @ArunPalanisamy You can make this test database by your own https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YNtU_2P6tHwBSMa4s7rtovk9h69xJ4mo/view?usp=sharing
The base is not something that you can't see it's just a test base, so if it's help - ok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the below query

```
select region,cnt from (
    select countries.region,
           count(countries.region) as cnt,
           dense_rank() over (order by count(countries.region)) AS ordr
    from teams join engineers on teams.id = engineers.team_id 
               join countries on countries.id = engineers.country_id
    group by countries.region 
        )a
where ordr=2
```

[***Check Demo Here***](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=7193f2cf56203f05c46e064f46356757)

Comment: Thank you. Helped me a lot!

Comment: Welcome. Glad I could help! @Lotarc

Comment: I've tried something like this but i couldn't understand how to make joins. Now i understand. Thanks.

Comment: This gives ambiguous results when there are multiple regions tied for the second lowest count.

Comment: It also gives results when every region has the same count (ie. there is no second lowest).

Comment: Fixed! @Z4-tier

Answer (score 0):

This can be done without window functions, using something like this:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        countries.region, 
        COUNT(countries.region) AS ct
    FROM 
        teams 
        INNER JOIN engineers 
            ON teams.id = engineers.team_id 
        INNER JOIN countries 
            ON countries.id = engineers.country_id 
    GROUP BY
        countries.region
)
SELECT
    region, 
    ct
FROM
    cte
GROUP BY 
    region,
    ct
HAVING
    ct = (SELECT MIN(ct) FROM cte WHERE ct <> (SELECT MIN(ct) FROM cte))
;
```